# Hosting a database on a VM

Tags: mongodb, centos, virtual-machine, web-hosting

I need some help understanding how to connect my local machine to a separately hosted database on a different machine.

**Context:**

I have ssh'd into my host machine (hereafter referred to as VM) and installed MongoDB. The VM runs CentOS and I have no restrictions beyond that.

**Goal**

My goal is to interact with the VM remotely via my local client on my local machine (Mac), perhaps through some sort of API (direct connection works as well). I'm willing to create that API, but I need to actually establish some sort of contact before that can happen. How can I actually deliver requests from my local machine to the VM, and therefore to my database?

**Edit #1**:

I should add that this is not exclusive to MongoDB and its host machine. I have several other NoSQL databases (each on their own individual machine). I'm hoping that if I can find a way to make one work, the rest will follow the same pattern.

Comment: You'll be connecting to MongoDB with help of MongoDB drivers for appropriate programming language. https://api.mongodb.org

Comment: I have voted to close here because you have left out so many relevant details.  For example: what have you tried? how is it failing (what is the error)? are you using the mongo shell? what about normal checks to make sure the port is open/listening and the service is actually running?

Comment: @AdamComerford The reason those are left out is because I frankly have (had) no idea where to start, which is why I posted the question. I also mentioned that this not exclusive to mongo, so I deliberately kept it vague so I can get high-level answers. I'm investigating the drivers now, and will update the question when I find a solution.

Comment: I think you should re-read the guidelines for the site, you are specifically asked to show what you have done to solve the issue, and what the outcome was - vague questions like this will be closed due to lack of detail

Comment: @AdamComerford I agree that parts of my question were lacking and I'll take care to provide more information in the future. If "vague" or "broad" questions are discouraged, where should I ask them? I've found that these kinds of questions do have merit and they've helped me in the past to find a way to approach strange topics and I'd like for my questions to help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I found out that the firewalls were preventing me from connecting to MongoDB on my remote server. So here is how I finally connected and verified:

### Remote Server

Stop the firewall:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Start up Mongo:

```
mongod
```

### Local Client

Form connection using Mongo

```
mongo REMOTE_IP
```

or

```
mongo REMOTE_DOMAIN_NAME
```